# Background image not filling circle - D3/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

See below image - 
I cannot get my image to take up the entire of the circle, if I increase the height then the picture just lowers, I tried hard to replicate the issue in code for a minimal version but im sorry I just wasnt able to do it, im hoping if i show the code then that is good enough and perhaps somebody can spot something I am missing.

The image is correctly filling most of the circle as you can see, and the circle does just fill properly if i just fill -> colour.

[image]

The code:

I am appending a pattern first as i have seen online, and then calling on the ID of that for the image to load in as fill (url).

Am I missing something? Thanks for any help possible.

```
insightAddCircleNodes(onClick: (node: EngagementGraphNode) => void): void {

const imgUrl = "https://ewsqa-images.weforum.org/topics/a1Gb0000001k6I5EAI/standard";
const circle = this.group
  .selectAll('circle.node')
  .data(this.nodes)
  .enter();


circle
  .append("pattern")
  .attr("id", "venus")
  .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", imgUrl)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 1)
  .attr("height", 1);


circle
  // Centre - main node
  .filter(node => !node.parent)
  .append('circle')
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
  .style('fill', node => `url(#venus)`)  <------- HERE IS WHERE I USE THE IMAGE
  // .style('fill', node => `url("engagement/${this.nodes[0].id}#pattern-${node.indicator.icon}")`)

  .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
  .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
  .on('click', node => onClick(node));
```

My expected result is that the image in the background takes up the entire of the centre circle. I'm actually not entirely sure how the size of the circles are set but I was assuming that as I am using '100%' then that should fill it, also as i mentioned if I say try to increase the height of the pattern and image, it just moves the image lower.

Comment: you don't use a square image

Comment: Is there not a way of say, zooming on the image so it will fill the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", imgUrl)
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 1)
.attr("height", 1)
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position and scale the image in the pattern using object viewport coordinates [0..1].

Note: **xlink:href** is deprecated, use **href** instead

The image is 768x512, that is 1.5:1. You then need to move the x coord of start drawing 0.25 to the left, so x=-0.25.

Using this method you can choose whatever part of the image you want to fill the pattern.

```
...
.append("image")
.attr("href", imgUrl)
.attr("x", -0.25)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 1.5)
.attr("height", 1);
```